# при вводе в инпут код цвета добавлять в начало символ #

Tags: javascript, jquery

при вводе пользователем номер hex цвета например b1b1b1, добавлять символ # если он забыл написать.
html:

```
<input type="text" class="color-scheme__input-color">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант (IE 11+):

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.value[0] != '#') {
        this.value = '#' + this.value;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Нужен перевод в `jQuery`?

**UPD**

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
    let $me = $(this);
    if ($me.val()[0] != "#") {
        $me.val( "#" + $me.val() )
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Если не сложно то можно вариант и в jquery

Comment: @DimaVleskov Обновил ответ